# How to pass a List (initialized as an ArrayList) to a method in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to pass the following List to a method but I am not sure of what parameter to use. When I pass it as a List, it appears empty. Can you please tell what I am doing wrong?

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
list.add("b");
list.add("c");

doStuff(list1);


public void doStuff(List<String> list1){
       //This outputs 0, even though I added two values to the list
       System.out.println(list.size());

}
```

Comment: make sure you initialized arraylist once. and put your whole class so we figure out what's the problem.

Comment: @avi Have a look at my code for an explanation of what is going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this code compiles

```
public void doStuff(List<String> list1){
       System.out.println(list.size());  // this is NOT the parameter passed in

}
```

then it must mean that `list` is a field in your class

so when you do

```
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
```

you are adding to this field object, not `list1` which is being passed.

Try

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add("b");   // list1
list1.add("c");   // list1

doStuff(list1);


public void doStuff(List<String> list1){
       // should print 2
       System.out.println(list1.size());  // list1

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You added strings to `list`, but you are passing `list1`, not `list`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList();
        list1.add("b");
        list1.add("c");
        doStuff(list1);



    }
    public static void doStuff(List<String> list1){
           //This outputs 0, even though I added two values to the list
           System.out.println(list1.size());

    }
```

Comment: I realized I forgot to call the function, but that's not the solution.

Comment: once check with my answer, its working fine now.